Translating pdf file stored on google storage using Google Translate Service Client in Java and storing translated file on same path of google storage
I have written function accepting 2 parameters

Signed URL as parameter (Url of file stored on google storage)
Destination language
It translates the file in destination language and stores on the same path with some extra text in file name (e.g. filename_translated) and returns signed Url of translated file

Now the issue I am facing is I cannot open file using the signed Url and getting following error
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Details>No such object: we-aid-translation/3159_Invoice-24BD5880- 
    0009_DE_translations.pdf</Details>
</Error>

Following is the code I am using for creating Url of translated file
TranslateDocumentResponse response = client.translateDocument(request);
log.info("response: {}", response.toString());
String fileNameWithoutExtension = inputFileName.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
String translatedDocumentUri = outputPrefix + fileNameWithoutExtension + "_" + targetLanguage + "_translations." + fileExtension;
log.info("translated document Uri {}", translatedDocumentUri);
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(translationBucketName, fileNameWithoutExtension + "_" + targetLanguage + "_translations." + fileExtension);
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("application/pdf").build();
URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, signedUrlExpiryTimeInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 
Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());

log.info("Translated document signed URL: " + signedUrl);
return Utilities.sendHttpResponse(HttpStatus.OK, Constants.SUCCESS, signedUrl.toString());

PS: If I access manually google storage I find translated file placed there.
Edit 1:
My Mistake:
Later I identified that this error was because of a little mistake in signed Url generated i.e. it was not reffering to the file and the error was generated because of no file existing.
Problem Statement (Modified):
The file uploaded after translation is having ContentType or MimeType as application/octet-stream but I need application/pdf.
How can I fix it as following changes are not working
    String outputPrefix = "gs://we-aid-translation/"; 
    DocumentOutputConfig outputConfig = DocumentOutputConfig.newBuilder().setGcsDestination(GcsDestination.newBuilder().setOutputUriPrefix(outputPrefix).build()).setMimeType("application/pdf").build();

and
BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("application/pdf").build();enter code here

